# Django 1.7 remove field. Unknown field(s) (field) specified for Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have already many models in my application.
I have already used migrations in my project.

But when I want to remove a field from a model, the makemigration command show me :

```
Unknown field(s) (field) specified for Model
```

Where (fields) is equal to the field's name and Model is the model's name ?

Do you have any solution to resolve this issue ?

Comment: how are you executing the migration? in particular, are you specifying the app label, like `python manage.py makemigrations app_label` ?

Comment: Did you delete and/or tamper with any previous migrations?

Comment: Can you check does field exists in db?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm late. Yes DRC I execute make migration with application specified. And yes the field exists in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You may try modifying auto_now and auto_now_add with default = 'xxx', then the field can be called